# Details of choosing a random real number between 0 and 1; zero or infinitesmally zero?

Tags: probability

You know the classic question choosing a random real number beetween 0 and 1.Nearly every source says it is zero.I am wondering is it limitly(infinitesmally) zero or exactly zero?

Like 1/infinity is undetermined but in extended real lines it's limit is 0.Is probability also defined with limits in contunious random variables?

Answer (score 2):

The probability that a randomly chosen number in the interval $[0,1]$ is $u$ ($u$ a real number with $0\le u\le 1$) is (exactly) $0$.

But even the probability that the chosen number is rational (or even the probability that the chosen number is algebraic) is $0$ because the rational numbers (and even the algebraic numbers) form a set with measure $0$.

This follows from the fact that there are only countably many rational numbers (and even algebraic numbers), but uncountably many real numbers in the $[0,1]$.

That does not mean that it is impossible to choose $u$.

Only in the discrete case, $P(A)=0$ implies that $A$ is the impossible event.

Comment: why it exactly zero doesn't this question involves limit my intituation says it converges to 0 not exactly zero?

Comment: @Peter the two sentences in your answer seems to contradict each other.if probability is exactly 0 why it is not impossible to choose u.

Comment: @navinstudent This is not true , if we have a continous random variable. The probability is in this case not given by the formula $\frac{number\ of\  "good"\  cases}{number\ of\ possible\ cases}$, but it is defined via a measure defined on sets.

Comment: @navinstudent bevcause by the end of the day probability theory isn't really about choosing numbers at all. -- According to what we imagiine about "picking a number from $[0,1]$ uniformly at ranfom", there simply does not exist a positive number $p$ such that you can seriously expect that out of $10^{100000000}$, say,  pick-a-number experiments, about $p\cdot 10^{100000000}$ of the numbers equal $u$

Comment: @aintnosunshinewhenyouaregone See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely

Comment: @Peter I am basically asking why cant we say lets n denote a random continous event since there are infinite numbers i goes to infinity n/ni=zero

Comment: @Peter why is it faulty to aproach with limits rather than via measure?It is hard to convince it is zero it seems like infinitesmally 0 not exactly in manner of limits

Comment: You can use the argument with the limit for natural numbers. If we choose a random natural number, the probability that it is the $7$ , is $0$. In this case, you can argue that the probability tends to $0$ if the numbers you can choose tends to $\infty$. But this method fails, if you want to calculate the probability, that a random chosen number in $[0,1]$ is rational, because you would get an undefined ratio $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: The main problem is that you cannot actually choose a random natural number or a random number $[0,1]$. In the first case, you have infinite many possibilities, but we cannot name/identify arbitgary large numbers. In the second case, we also have the problem that most of the numbers chosen could not be named/identified.